# When can I factor (omit) "the" or a pronoun which repeats

Tags: definite-article, pronouns, determiners, ellipsis

I have this sentence

> The user can select or define distinguishing features of the anchor based on its attributes (e.g. id, class), [**its ?**] text or a pattern in the text.

I feel that I don't need to repeat "its" before "text", or use any article. Am I right at this sense?

What is the general rule?

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to consider here is that you have a series (list) of nouns, in this case consisting of three items:

> its **attributes**, [its] **text** or a **pattern in the text**

The possessive pronoun *its* is understood to be distributed through the list, which is why you are correct, and it is acceptable to omit it. Further examples of this with articles:

> Laura bought an apple, peach, pear, and plum.
>
> He is the judge, jury and executioner.

And with possessive pronouns:

> He likes his dog because of its color, temperament, and intelligence.
>
> I hired John because of his work ethic, programming skills, and excellent references.

Note, that it is also acceptable to keep the article/pronoun, and this is often done for emphasis/style:

> **the** truth, **the** whole truth, and nothing but **the** truth